# Get data from ManytoMany Relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```
class Speaker(models.Model):
    id_speaker = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()

class Session(models.Model):
    id_session = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    speakers = models.ManyToManyField(Speaker)
```

When I querying `Session.objects.all()`, I got the next sample data:

```
{
  "id_session": "UUID",
  "name": "Example name",
  "speakers": [
    {
      "id_speaker": "UUID",
      "name": "John Doe"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you see, I have the list of speakers of session, now the question is, how I could got the sessions of speaker, an example that how I want:

```
{
    "id_speaker": "UUID",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "sessions": [
        {
            "id_session": "UUID",
            "name": "Example name"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you wondering if I use django-rest-framework, the answer is YES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `related_name` [Django Related Name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Notice the `related_name` kwarg in ManyToManyField

```
class Speaker(models.Model):
    id_speaker = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()

class Session(models.Model):
    id_session = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    speakers = models.ManyToManyField(Speaker, related_name='sessions')
```

Then you can get all sessions from a speaker object

```
some_speaker.sessions.all()  #Returns sessions
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you're right, but in order to complete the answer, I had to add field `sessions` in serializer class.

Answer (score 0):

eh can't you change the structure of the model?

```
class Session(models.Model):
    id_session = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()


class Speaker(models.Model):
    id_speaker = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    session = models.ManyToManyField(Session)
```

Not sure if I understand your question correctly.